# Angular Firestore - how to get a doc without it's key

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire5

I'm working with Angular Firestore and I've been struggling with this particular task the last two days. Here is what I need: When user taps the save button, I call:

```
save(group: IGroup){
 if(group.id){
  this.update(group);
 }else{
  this.create(group);
 }
}
```

So far so good, it works fine when I call update and create methods. My problem is before calling the 'save' function in the first place. I have this schema:

```
(collection)groups -> (document)group -> (array)group.words
```

What I need to do is:

```
if(groups.last.words.length < 9){
  save(groups.last)
}else{
  save(new Group())
}
```

How can I achieve that by getting groups from Angular Firestore?

Comment: Are you saying you want to fetch a specfic document without knowing the ID of the document? Are you letting Firestore generate the Document IDs?

Comment: Yes and yes. And I use map and snapshot values to have the document ids.

Comment: So you do not fetch the documents before making changes to the `(array)group.words`. Is it possible to show any more code of what you are doing before the `save()` method is called?

Comment: @NicholasPesa thanks for putting some thought on this. I just managed to solve my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I solved my problem by declaring:

```
words: Array<IWord>;
```

and then populating it within 'subscribe':

```
this.words$.subscribe( result => {
  this.words = result;
});
```

Then I got my object from my 'words' array.